# How to replace hamburger icon with other icon in UWP xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have an application, I added other hamburger icon instead of default hamburger icon. It works in both Android and iOS but not in UWP. Is there any way to change the picture consistently?

Comment: Did you  set Icon manually on the MasterPage. ie in MasterDetailAppPageMaster.xaml ?

Comment: Yes. I added icon in navigationpage.Titleview

Answer (score 0):

I created a project, and this project I change the icon of the hamburger menu icon.

I have a solution in Android, but I think in iOS is the same way.

You have to create a Custom MasterDetailPageRenderer class and you have to change the icon from the OnLayout function.

**Project**
https://github.com/officialdoniald/Xamarin.Forms.CustomControls/blob/master/XamarinForms.CustomControls/XamarinForms.CustomControls.Android/CustomRenderer/MasterNavigationPageRenderer.cs

**Android**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMasterDetailPage), typeof(MasterNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace XamarinForms.CustomControls.Droid.CustomRenderer
{

    public class MasterNavigationPageRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
    {
        private static Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar GetToolbar() => (CrossCurrentActivity.Current?.Activity as MainActivity)?.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        private Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;

        public MasterNavigationPageRenderer() : base() { }

        public MasterNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        public MasterNavigationPageRenderer(IntPtr a, JniHandleOwnership b) : base() { }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        toolbar = GetToolbar();
        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            SetNavigationButton(Resource.Drawable.menu);
        }
    }
    private void SetNavigationButton(int resourceID)
    {
        var icon = Forms.Context.GetDrawable(resourceID);
        using (var drawable = ((BitmapDrawable)icon).Bitmap)
        using (var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(drawable, 80, 80, false))
        using (var newDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, bitmap))
        {
            toolbar.NavigationIcon = newDrawable;
        }
    }
}
```